# React website in iPhone Safari keyboard issue

Tags: ios, reactjs

I've developed react js web app and running on iPhone Safari browser, while editing something in textinput and opening keyboard there is some unwanted blank space coming at the bottom, Is there any way to resolve this?
facing issue like this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYOeT.png)